# How to send multiple form data in django?

Tags: python, html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

I have created the form in django for transfering multiple data in the database. How can I achieve this?
Since I want to create multiple choice question app and transfer the multiple data of form at once in th db.

Answer (score 1):

You Have Two Ways

Put different URLs in the action for the two forms. Then you'll have two different view functions to deal with the two different forms.

or

```
if 'data' in request.POST:
    # do 
elif 'data2' in request.POST:
    #do
```

Comment: I have never used two separate action URLs. Can you explain how this works? Is the form rendered from one view then POSTing to a different view? If so, how will the view that handled the rendering of the fields handle submitting the rest of the form fields without that field?

Comment: You can look at [this](https://www.codementor.io/@lakshminp/handling-multiple-forms-on-the-same-page-in-django-fv89t2s3j) blog to understand.